# Checking if all numbers in range are found in the array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I was given the assignment to write a method for finding if all of the numbers between 1-N are found in the array (not in any specific order).
I wrote this, but I get ArrayIndexOut of bound errors.
I would really appreciate some help.
Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;

public class test{

  public static boolean lol (int [] a){

      int[] counter = new int[a.length];
      for(int o=0;o<counter.length;o++){
          counter[o]=0;
      }
      for(int i=0; i<counter.length;i++){
          counter[a[i]]++;
      }
      int check=0;
      for(int t=0; t<counter.length;t++){
          if(counter[t]==1){
              check++;
          }
      }
        if(check==a.length){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)


{
  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  int b[] = {1,5,2,3,4};
  lol(b);
}
}
```

Comment: Help with what? Where does the exception occur? Why does it occur? What debugging have you done?

Comment: You might want to check the stack trace of the exception, take note of the line number and then tell people in which line the exception occurs.

Comment: Just noticing you don't need to initialize the `int[] counter` with zeros. They are filled with it automatically.

Comment: Also, what is N? Is it the size of the input array? If yes, are 1 and N as input-array values included or excluded?

Comment: Even with the fixes in the answers, this will only work if array contains only values in the proper range (either all values once, or with some values missing and some duplicated). It would never work, for example, for the array {1, 17, 42}. That would always throw rather than return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code makes no sense:

```
for(int i=0; i<counter.length;i++){
      counter[a[i]]++;
  }
```

you go through the `counter` array indices, but actually use them to index into `a`. Instead you should have

```
for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++){
      counter[a[i]]++;
  }
```

and, naturally, make sure that the `counter` array is large enough to accommodate the largest integer occurring in your input array.

Past that error there are more things to correct:

1. you don't need to initialize the array to 0 because it is already initialized;
2. `counter` could be a `boolean` array because you don't need counting, just existence;
3. if the range of numbers occurring in the input starts with 1, then you can use `a[i]-1` as the index into `counter` since you won't be using the zero index otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! I thought you needed to initialize arrays just like normal variables. I needed the counter array to be of an int type because I needed to check if the number was in the array more than once.

Comment: In that case I would recommend using `if (counter[t] > 0) check++;` instead of `if (counter[t] == 1) check++;` It is safer that way.

Comment: As for initialization, indeed you have to initialize the array *variable*, but not the array's *contents*.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined b as `int b[] = {1,5,2,3,4};`

Here b[1] is 5 while b.length is 5. Array index starts with 0 and goes uptil n-1 i.e. 4. Now in lol method, you try doing `counter[a[i]]++;` and if i is 1, then you are trying to do counter[5]++ which is out of range of an array.

Instead, you should use `counter[a[i]-1]++;`

Couple of points:

Your code:

```
for(int o=0;o<counter.length;o++){
    counter[o]=0;
}
```

Is not needed as counter array elements would be by default initialized to 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void hasRange(int n, int[] numbers) {
    boolean result = true;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (Arrays.asList(numbers).contains(i) == false) {
            result = false;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
counter[a[i]]++;
```

In this line you should say:

```
counter[a[i]-1]++;
```

You should also delete your counter array at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is happening on this line

```
counter[a[i]]++;
```

On your b[] array, there is a value of 5 inside. This value is trying to index your counter[] array which has range [0,4].

Answer (score 0):

The only possible source for an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in your code is

```
for(int i=0; i<counter.length;i++){
     counter[a[i]]++;
}
```

Obviously, the array `a` contains elements that are larger than its length minus one.